# java code for for converting arrays [{},{}] to {} {} with multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

How can i write a java code for the input

```
[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}
]

[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":2,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":3,"unit":""}
]
```

so that i should get output as below

```
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":2,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":3,"unit":""}
```

can someone help me out in doing this?

Comment: you can use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` class and iterate throughout the `JSONArray` and put each objects into a `JSONObject`.  It is as simple as that .Thank You:)

Comment: There are several ways of doing this. @Vikrant has already suggested one solution. To better help you, share the code that you wrote we can help you in in that direction.

Comment: Hey thanks for ur replies ... actually i m new to java and i have not worked much on json...so any one of u can help me in writing the whole code? @VikrantKashyap ,Salman ,Anil

Comment: @SachinKademane the below code is functional, please accept the answer

Comment: @SachinKademane please add some of your project code to know what exactly datatype used to hold the `JsonArray`. please update your question with the you code, then only we will help you out to write the exact code. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here , the input should be given to a variable like ,


x=[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}
]

[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":2,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":3,"unit":""}
]
```

I am not getting what should be the datatype of x and how to declare.
    Because here i need to pass the input dynamically from an another application and it will not be added manually every time (data will be generated automatically), this is like an interface for conversion.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Store the arrays as variables. Loop over each array. Loop through each object in each array. Print each object.

Pseudo code only

```
var i = array.length;
while(i--){ // outer loop
  var j = array.length;
  while(j--) { // inner loop
    print[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: @Vikranth Kashyap each second i ll be getting input as arrays as shown above and i need output as
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}.......